# Is a reversed path analysis a nested model? (SEM)

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan, path-model

I'm trying to compare whether a forward/direct path analysis is a better fit to the same data than a reversed model. I'm using the `SEM` function of the `LAVAAN` package, below is shortened syntax for the models. Both are predicting the same outcome (Y), but in the first, I've proposed that the mediators (M1 and M2) mediate the link between X1 and Y (controlling for X2), and in the second I've swapped these over.

I'm unsure if these are nested, as they contain the same variables on the same data, with only the direction of the effects being different. If they are nested, I would likely use CFI, RMSEA, etc. to compare them, otherwise, would AIC and BIC be a better idea?

```
directModel<-  "Y ~ X1 + X2 + M1 + M2
  M1 ~ X1
  M2 ~ X1" 

reverseModel<-  "Y~ X1 + X2 + M1 + M2
  X1 ~ M1
  X1 ~ M2"
```

Thanks for any help, I've found it difficult to put this into simple words to google it!

Answer (score 1):

They are not nested. For models to be nested you must be able to get from one to the other by only adding parameters (or taking away parameters).

To get from directModel to reverseModel, you must remove two parameters:

```
M1 ~ X1
M2 ~ X1
```

And add two:

```
X1 ~ M1
X1 ~ M2
```

There will probably be something going on with covariances too.

Comment: Is this not the case with the current model? Because as you said you can add 2 and remove 2 parameters to get from each model? Also, if I stated the effect was reciprocal (so both for directModel: M1 ~ X1, X1 ~ M1, M2 ~ X1, X1 ~ M2), wouldn't this be nested?  Although, I had a go at the fit indices and the second model has no Df, probably an indicator this wouldn't work. Thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: You can only add. Or only take away.